# Photos on Mac not syncing with iCloud Photo Library

Tags: icloud, photos

I have enabled the iCloud Photo Library on my iPad and MacBook. While I was traveling, I uploaded some photos directly into my library at icloud.com using a web browser. The photos I uploaded then appeared on my iPad, but not my MacBook.

I have tried the following things with no success:

1. Closing and opening Photos
2. Restarting the MacBook
3. Turning iCloud Photo Library on and off in Preferences
4. Leaving the computer on overnight to allow the sync to sort itself out.

What else could I try?

I just enabled iCloud Photo Library on the MacBook and it has yet to complete the upload of all 50,000 of my photos to iCloud. Perhaps this is part of the problem?

I am running Yosemite 10.10.4

**UPDATE:** Since I reported this problem three months ago, I've upgraded the iPad to iOS 9 and the laptop to El Capitan, but the problem still remains. My only guess, is that the syncing won't start until the initial upload of the photo library is complete.

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates on your problem? Did it finally sync? And if yes, how long did it take? I uploaded photos directly to icloud photos library and now I am waiting for them to appear on my mac, but so far they have not.

Comment: Unfortunately no updates. The initial upload sync is still continuing. I guess that once that is complete, it will start syncing photos properly...